# Integrating react router with material ui is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I am trying to integrate react-router with material ui in sidebar menu, but it is not working. When I click on the menu item, only url changes but component doesn't load. I tried it with the guide on [https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#link], but getting weird results everytime I try to change something in the code. My app components are as below,

layout.js

```
import React, {useCallback, useState} from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import {
  Switch,
  Route,
  BrowserRouter as Router
}from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  makeStyles,
  useTheme
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
  Drawer,
  CssBaseline,
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  IconButton,
  Typography,
  Divider,
  List,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import {MenuItem} from "./menu";
import {menu} from "./menuitems";
import {TheDowTheory} from "./DowTheory";
import {HomePage} from "../Home/Home";



const drawerWidth = 280;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: 36,
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
  },
  drawerOpen: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  drawerClose: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    width: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: theme.spacing(9) + 1,
    },
  },
  toolbar: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

export const MiniDrawer = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);

  const toggle = useCallback(
    () => setOpen(!open),
    [open],
  );

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={classes.appBar}
        style={{backgroundColor:'white'}}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={toggle}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, {
              [classes.open]: !open,
            })}
            style={{color:'#10375c'}}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h4"
                      noWrap
                      style={{color:'#10375c'}}
          >
            StockViz
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        variant="permanent"
        className={clsx(classes.drawer, {
          [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
          [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
        })}
        classes={{
          paper: clsx({
            [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
            [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
          }),
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.toolbar}>
          <IconButton onClick={toggle} />
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {menu.map((item, key) => <MenuItem key={key} item={item} />)}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
              <Route exact path='/thedowtheory' component={TheDowTheory} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

menu.js

```
import React, {forwardRef, Fragment, useMemo, useState} from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import ExpandLess from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandLess';
import ExpandMore from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import {hasChildren} from "./utils";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import {
  Link,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
} from "react-router-dom";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  link: {
    textDecoration: 'none',
    color: theme.palette.text.primary
  }
}))


const SingleLevel = ({ item }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Router>
      <Link to={item.to} className={classes.link}>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={item.title} />
        </ListItem>
      </Link>
    </Router>
  );
};

const MultiLevel = ({ item }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { items: children } = item;
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Link to={item.to} className={classes.link}>
        <ListItem button onClick={handleClick}>
        <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={item.title} />
        {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
      </ListItem>
      <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <List component='div'
              disablePadding
        >
                {children.map((child, key) => (
                        <MenuItem key={key} item={child} />
                ))}
        </List>
      </Collapse>
      </Link>
    </Router>
  );
};

export const MenuItem = ({ item }) => {
  const Component = hasChildren(item) ? MultiLevel : SingleLevel;
  return <Component item={item} />;
};
```

menuitems.js

```
import HomeOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/HomeOutlined";
import LocalLibraryOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LocalLibraryOutlined";
import TrendingUpOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/TrendingUpOutlined";
import DescriptionOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/DescriptionOutlined";
import React from "react";
import {HomePage} from "../Home/Home";
import {TheDowTheory} from "./DowTheory";


export const menu = [
  {
    icon: <HomeOutlinedIcon/>,
    title: 'Home',
    to: '/',
    component: HomePage,
    items: []
  },
  {
    icon: <LocalLibraryOutlinedIcon/>,
    title: 'Education',
    items: [
      {
        title:'Technical Analysis',
        items: [
          {
            title: 'Introduction',
            component: 'Technical',
            to: '/technical'
          },
          {
            title: 'The Dow Theory',
            component: TheDowTheory,
            to: '/thedowtheory'
          },
          {
            title: 'Charts & Chart Patterns',
            component: 'Charts',
            to: '/chart'
          },
          {
            title: 'Trend & Trend Lines',
            component: 'Trends',
            to: '/trendlines'
          },
          {
            title: 'Support & Resistance',
            component: 'Support',
            to: '/sandr'
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        title:'Fundamental Analysis',
        items: [
          {
            title: 'Introduction',
            component: 'Technical',
            to: '/fundamental'
          },
          {
            title: 'The Dow Theory',
            component: 'Technical',
            to: '/thedowtheory'
          },
          {
            title: 'Charts & Chart Patterns',
            component: 'Technical',
            to: '/chart'
          },
          {
            title: 'Trend & Trend Lines',
            component: 'Technical',
            to: '/trendlines'
          },
          {
            title: 'Support & Resistance',
            component: 'Technical',
            to: '/sandr'
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        title:'Elliot Wave Analysis',
        items: [
          {
            title: 'Introduction',
            component: 'Technical',
            to: '/elliot'
          },
          {
            title: 'The Dow Theory',
            component: 'Technical',
            to: '/thedowtheory'
          },
          {
            title: 'Charts & Chart Patterns',
            component: 'Technical',
            to: '/chart'
          },
          {
            title: 'Trend & Trend Lines',
            to: '/trendlines'
          },
          {
            title: 'Support & Resistance',
            to: '/sandr'
          },
        ]
      },
      ]
  },
  {
    icon: <TrendingUpOutlinedIcon/>,
    to: '/options',
    component: 'Options',
    title: 'Options'
  },
  {
    icon: <DescriptionOutlinedIcon/>,
    to: '/blog',
    component: 'Blog',
    title: 'Blog'
  },
]
```

utils.js

```
import React from "react";

export function hasChildren(item) {
  const { items: children } = item;

  if (children === undefined) {
    return false;
  }

  if (children.constructor !== Array) {
    return false;
  }

  if (children.length === 0) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Is it required to have `component` property on your menu items? I see `component: HomePage` for the  home.

Comment: I have put it to route it programmatically. Currently I am not using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Yogendra Kumar This answer is a continuation from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63304950/8062659). I will use the same code with enhancement to add support for React Router.

---

First, I would change my `SingleLevel` component to use `Link` component from `react-router-dom`. This can be done by passing `component={Link}` to `ListItem`. It's also worth noting that if the current item has no `to` property, I would like the user to be redirected to 404 page.

*Read the guides on integrating `react-router-dom` to `material-ui` [here](https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#routing-libraries).*

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
...

const SingleLevel = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <ListItem button component={Link} to={item.to || "/404"}>
      <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={item.title} />
    </ListItem>
  );
};
```

This changes is not needed for `MultiLevel`'s `ListItem` component, because we don't want to link user to a page when its item is clicked — but show its collapsed items only.

Next, I would create a  `Routes` component that will have all of my route configurations.

*`react-router-dom` [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)*

**Routes.js**

```js
export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route path="/thedowtheory" component={TheDowTheory} />
      <Route path="/trendlines" component={TrendLines} />
      <Route path="/sandr" component={SandR} />
      <Route path="/chart" component={Chart} />

      <Route path="/404" component={NotFound} />
      <Redirect to="/404" />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Lastly, I will rename the `App.js` file to `Nav.js` because I wan't `App.js` to have these codes instead

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import Nav from "./Nav";
import Routes from "./Routes";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <Nav />
        <Routes />
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit clever-ives-z9fw3]

@Yogendra Kumar, this solution doesn't take account the `component` property from `menu.js`.

Answer (score -1):

Component `Menu` must be inside of `Router` if you wanna direct to another component.

Comment: which Menu component?

Comment: in file `layout.js`. Move tag `Router` out as the parent tag of this component.

Comment: Can you put your code on codepen.io. So we can take a look at this.