# React - Close MUI drawer from nested menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using this excellent example ([Nested sidebar menu with material ui and Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63297109/nested-sidebar-menu-with-material-ui-and-reactjs)) to build a dynamic nested menu for my application.  On top of that I'm trying to go one step further and put it into a Material UI appbar/temporary drawer.  What I'd like to achieve is closing the drawer when the user clicks on one of the lowest level item (SingleLevel) however I'm having a tough time passing the toggleDrawer function down to the menu.  When I handle the click at SingleLevel I consistently get a 'toggle is not a function' error.

I'm relatively new to this so I'm sure it's something easy and obvious.  Many thanks for any answers/comments.

EDIT: Here's a sandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/temporarydrawer-material-demo-forked-v11ur

Code is as follows:

Appbar.js

```
export default function AppBar(props) {

  const [drawerstate, setDrawerstate] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleDrawer = (state, isopen) => (event) => {

    if (event.type === 'keydown' && (event.key === 'Tab' || event.key === 'Shift')) {
      return;
    }

    setDrawerstate({ ...state, left: isopen });

  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <AppBar position="static" color="secondary">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            size="large"
            edge="start"
            color="primary"
            aria-label="menu"
            onClick={toggleDrawer('left', true)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
        </Toolbar>
        <Drawer
          anchor='left'
          open={drawerstate['left']}
          onClose={toggleDrawer('left', false)}
        >
          <Box>
            <AppMenu toggleDrawer={toggleDrawer} />
          </Box>
        </Drawer>
      </AppBar>
    </Box >
  )
}
```

Menu.js

```
export default function AppMenu(props) {
    return MenuItemsJSON.map((item, key) => <MenuItem  key={key} item={item} toggleDrawer={props.toggleDrawer} />);
}

const MenuItem = ({ item, toggleDrawer }) => {

    const MenuComponent = hasChildren(item) ? MultiLevel : SingleLevel;
    return <MenuComponent item={item} toggleDrawer={toggleDrawer} />;
  };
  
  const SingleLevel = ({ item, toggleDrawer }) => {
    
    const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(toggleDrawer);
    
    return (
      <ListItem button onClick={() => { toggle('left', false) }}>
        <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={item.title}   />
      </ListItem>
    );
  };
  
  const MultiLevel = ({ item }) => {
    const { items: children } = item;
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  
    const handleClick = () => {
      setOpen((prev) => !prev);
    };
  
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ListItem button onClick={handleClick}>
          <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={item.title} secondary={item.description} />
          {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
        </ListItem>
        <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          <List component="div" disablePadding>
            {children.map((child, key) => (
              <MenuItem key={key} item={child} />
            ))}
          </List>
        </Collapse>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call a react hook inside of any function that is not a react component. Please see [React Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

What you could do instead is pass setToggle directly into the Drawer component as a prop and do something like this for it's onClick attribute:

```
onClick={() => setToggle(<value>)}
```

Comment: And then pass it from the drawer into the menu inside it?  My goal is to be able to close the drawer from the menu (child of the drawer).  I added a sandbox above if it makes the problem more clear

Comment: Your sandbox isn't working for me unfortunately. But yes you could do that. With your current setup though I would just pass setToggle into the menu as a prop and call it the same way as shown above.

Comment: Here's a fixed sandbox...sorry about that.   https://codesandbox.io/s/temporarydrawer-material-demo-forked-v11ur